# $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, settimeout

I am new to the jquery mobile while making ajax request i use to display the loading message until getting the response from sever. I tried a lot for this but no use.can any one help me out from this issue thanks in advance..

bellow ajax call code

```
        $.ajax({ 
    url: "url", 
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                  
    beforeSend: function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
     $.mobile.loading('show');},1);  
     },
     success: function(msg) {
      // $.mobile.loading('hide');
     $.each(msg.empWall, function() {   
      alert(this.name);          
      });
      },
      error: function(err) {
      alert(err.toString());
      },
      complete: function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
     $.mobile.loading('hide');
     },1);  
     });
```

Comment: beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }, //Show 
            complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() }, //Hide spinner this is not working in ajax call

Comment: Tell me also what browser are you using?

Comment: ah excellent, give me a sec, I have an answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web-kit browser have a problem with programatical execution of jQuery Mobile loader, but it can be executed like this:

**Show:**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.loading('show');
},1);
```

**Hide:**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
},1);
```

They just need a small delay caused by **`setTimeout`** or **`setInterval`** function.

Comment: what version of jQuery Mobile are you using?

Comment: 1.3.1 i am using, can you look at my ajax call

Comment: Tell me was $.ajax call successful?

Comment: Gajotres if have any sample can you share it that it could helps me alot

Comment: before I show you an example do me one last thing, comment this line: $.mobile.loading('hide'); . Maybe ajax call is so fast ajax loader is hidden immediately.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30694/discussion-between-srikanth-and-gajotres)

Comment: i was already commented that line and intentionally  i am taking slow response from server to see the spinner

Comment: Ok next question, do you load your jQuery Mobile css from local source or remotely from jQuery CDN?

Comment: i am using <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css\jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.min.css" /> these two

Comment: Excellent, no go to css directory and tell me do you have directory called images?

Comment: oh god finally working . i made mistake kept images folder out side the css folder thank  you very much....Gajotres

Comment: Can we restrict user to stop the interaction with UI untill response get from sever or manually disable the buttons

Comment: I am glad to help. You were patient and I congratulate you on that.

Comment: You can try to set async : false to ajax properties, or you can create an empty transparent div, set it to position absolute to cover whole page. Show it with loader and hide it when you hide loader.