# How can I have a jQuery mobile spinner until data loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

**EDIT:** I specifically want a solution working with jQuery Mobile. jQuery Mobile has specific methods (as far as I understand it) to do *EXACTLY* what I want to do. I don't want plain Javascript with a spinning gif. That's not why I posted this question. Any accepted answer will involve jQuery Mobile or explain to me why this isn't possible or why I shouldn't want to use jQuery Mobile for this functionality (assuming jQuery Mobile is already loaded onto the page of my application)

I have this code and I've tried a variety of different ways to get a jQuery mobile spinner working in PhoneGap with absolutely no success. My latest attempt is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/random.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
        <title>Reddit</title>
        <script>
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
            $.mobile.loading('show');
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/random.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">

                <h2>Subreddit Name</h2>
                <div id="output"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/snoocore/Snoocore-standalone.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                var reddit = new window.Snoocore({
                    userAgent: 'App Name',
                    login: {username: 'username', password: 'password'}
                });
                reddit.login();
    // Get information about a slice of a listing:
                function printSlice(slice) {
                    slice.stickied.forEach(function(item, i) {
                        var div = document.getElementById('output');
                        var p = document.createElement("p");
                        var ahref = document.createElement("a");
                        ahref.setAttribute("href", "redditarticle.html?link=" + item.data.id);
                        ahref.innerHTML = '**STICKY**' + item.data.title;
                        p.appendChild(ahref);
                        div.appendChild(p);
                    });
                    slice.children.forEach(function(child, i) {
                        var div = document.getElementById('output');
                        //div.setAttribute("")
                        var p = document.createElement("p");
                        var ahref = document.createElement("a");
                        ahref.setAttribute("href", "redditarticle.html?link=" + child.data.id);
                        ahref.innerHTML = child.data.title;
                        p.appendChild(ahref);
                        div.appendChild(p);
                    });
                }
                function getAll() {
                    var children = [];
                    function handleSlice(slice) {
                        if (slice.empty) {
                            return children;
                        }
                        printSlice(slice);
                        children = children.concat(slice.children);
                        if (slice.count > 1) {
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            return slice.next().then(handleSlice);
                        }
                    }
                    return reddit('/r/subreddit/hot').listing({
                        limit: 25,
                    }).then(handleSlice);
                }
                getAll().done();
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to show a loading icon until the script can pull the data from Reddit.

How do I make that happen? I've tried to do things on mobileinit, I've tried to do things on pagecreate and pagebeforecreate and no luck with anything.

All I want is a simple mobile spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery mobile loaders work as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/9ybagLpb/2/

Try to remove the following:

```
   <script>
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        $.mobile.loading('show');
   </script>
```

And update your script to:

```
 (function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('show');
    },1);  

    var reddit = new window.Snoocore({
        userAgent: 'App Name',
        login: {
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password'
        }
    });
    reddit.login();
    // Get information about a slice of a listing:
    function printSlice(slice) {
        slice.stickied.forEach(function (item, i) {
            var div = document.getElementById('output');
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            var ahref = document.createElement("a");
            ahref.setAttribute("href", "redditarticle.html?link=" + item.data.id);
            ahref.innerHTML = '**STICKY**' + item.data.title;
            p.appendChild(ahref);
            div.appendChild(p);
        });
        slice.children.forEach(function (child, i) {
            var div = document.getElementById('output');
            //div.setAttribute("")
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            var ahref = document.createElement("a");
            ahref.setAttribute("href", "redditarticle.html?link=" + child.data.id);
            ahref.innerHTML = child.data.title;
            p.appendChild(ahref);
            div.appendChild(p);
        });
    }

    function getAll() {
        var children = [];

        function handleSlice(slice) {
            if (slice.empty) {
                return children;
            }
            printSlice(slice);
            children = children.concat(slice.children);
            if (slice.count > 1) {
                return;
            } else {
                return slice.next().then(handleSlice);
            }
        }
        return reddit('/r/subreddit/hot').listing({
            limit: 25,
        }).then(handleSlice);
    }
    getAll().done(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        },1);  
    });
})();
```

**NOTE** Web-kit browser have a problem with programatical execution of jQuery Mobile loader as explained here 
[$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772919/mobile-showpageloadingmsg-is-not-working)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll try it with my credentials and with a specific subreddit later today.

Comment: Cool, the loaders work as you can see from this basic fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9ybagLpb/2/ . Just a matter of calling the two from the correct places like in my example. Hope it helps!

Comment: It's actually due to some weirdness in Webkit browsers that nothing we were doing was working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772919/mobile-showpageloadingmsg-is-not-working

Comment: I'll give you the vote if you add that part to it, as otherwise this works great.

Answer (score 1):

Use an overlay that is faded out when the page is fully loaded.

HTML

```
 <div id="loadingOverlay">
     <img src="pageload.gif" alt="The page is loading" />
     Please Wait
 </div>
```

Script

```
 $(window).load(function(){
        $('#loadingOverlay').fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: Almost correct (if I read the question correctly): move the fadeOut() to the reddit callback (`handleSlide()` probably)

Comment: This doesn't seem similar to any other examples I've seen - most seem to go based on mobileinit.

Comment: And this also didn't seem to work in my application.

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript, html and css:

html:

```
<div id="loader">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#loader {
position:fixed;
z-index:9999;
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;
background-color: green;
background-image:url('urlToGifAnimation');
background-position: center;
background-size: 50px 50px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
//Hide loader
var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
loader.style.opcaity=0;
loader.style.display='none';
}
```

`window.onload` will not trigger until everything is loaded(dom, images...)

You don't need any jquery and it is not reccomended to use if a javascript solution is available.

Comment: As far as I am aware, jQuery mobile has specific methods to ensure everything is done in the correct order to keep consistent styling.

Comment: my solution is consistent cross browser and its easily translated into jquery if that's what you want